# Add shortcut for character

Tags: keyboard, release-hera

I just bought a [Samsung Style S51 Pro notebook](https://www.samsung.com/br/pc/notebook-style-s51-np760xbe-xw1br/), however, some genius in Samsung decided to not include the backslash and pipeline key. My keyboard layout is Portuguese Brazil (in the English version you will see the keyboard fine).

My question is: how can I add a shortcut so I can type these characters?

I'm using Elementary OS 5.1 Hera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using AutoKey, it's a software for shortcuts, there is a functionality that allows you to make hotkeys for specifics task, if you know Python then u can try it out

Comment: Yes, however AutoKey is not working. I tried the AutoKey in a Xubuntu VM (in another computer) and worked fine.

Comment: Ok. It worked, but not with the 'super' key.